# How do I set up node app to access PostgreSQL using typeorm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I found a website https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm that, in a few steps, creates a typescript application able to connect to a PostgreSQL database. I followed the steps and modified the example to connect to my own existing database and successfully fetch the contents of one table. What my goal is though is to create a REST service deployed to nodeJS that's able to provide access to persistent data stored in the PostgreSQL database. I found another website with an example (over 2 parts) of all that I wanted to do and more. https://itnext.io/production-ready-node-js-rest-apis-setup-using-typescript-postgresql-and-redis-a9525871407 Part 2 was to go into the integration of PostgreSQL. It seems that Part 2 was never published, so I was left with a node app that looks like a great start. So I tried by myself to integrate the missing pieces so that the code deployed to the node REST service could access my database. 
While the code works as expected when using this script to start it:

```
"start": "ts-node src/index.ts"
```

This script causes an error in the entity source on the import statement to pull in the typeorm required classes:

```
"dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node ./build/src/index.js\""
```

Here's the error:

```
/Users/jboss/projects/typescript/backend/src/entity/Banners.ts:1
import { Column, Entity, BaseEntity } from "typeorm";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Function.PlatformTools.load (/Users/jboss/projects/typescript/backend/node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js:114:28)
    at /Users/jboss/projects/typescript/backend/node_modules/typeorm/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:39:69
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

This is the ormconfig content:

```
{
   "type": "postgres",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 5432,
   "username": "jboss",
   "password": "bluegrass",
   "database": "video",
   "synchronize": false,
   "logging": true,
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
}
```

Here's the package.json content:

```
{
   "name": "backend",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
   "devDependencies": {
      "ts-node": "3.3.0",
      "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
      "typescript": "3.3.3333"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "pg": "^7.18.2",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
      "typeorm": "^0.2.24"
   },
   "scripts": {
      "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node ./build/src/index.js\"",
      "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
      "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
   }
}
```

Here's the tsconfig.json content:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es5",
         "es6"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": true
   }
}
```

I'm hoping someone can give me a hint as to what I need to do to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the "entities" property in your ormconfig.json.

It should be something like

```
{
  //...
  "entities": ["build/src/entity/*.*"]
}
```